# absolute path URL in text field causing problems

Tags: fields, text-formatting

i've got a text field that i'm using to include an optional url in entries which are used for homepage announcements. if a url is included, the homepage will link to that url. if not, it will link to the announcement itself:

```
<a href="{if announcement_redirect}{announcement_redirect}{if:else}{site_url}announcement/{entry_id}/{/if}">
```

works like a charm with local, relative urls (ie: /event/1234/). but when an absolute path is entered (ie: http://some.biz), it adds an anchor tag around the url and becomes `<a href="<a href="http://some.biz">http://some.biz</a>">` which is clearly not great.

the field's Default Text Formatting is set to None, and i even ran the "Update all existing channel entries with new formatting choice?" option to be sure of it.

i was running EE 2.6.1 and hoped an upgrade to 2.7.3 would fix it, but that hasn't had any effect either.

any ideas on how to nix the auto-HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have 'Automatically turn URLs and email addresses into links?' set to 'no' in the channel's preferences?

Comment: well, i'll be. i never noticed the individual Channel Preferences!

CP Home > Administration > Channels > Channel Preferences: Announcements

turning it off NOW. thank you!